# Images and preimages of lines under complex sine and square function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having an issue with an exercise regarding the images and preimages of lines under complex functions

> Sketch the images and preimages of the coordinate lines $x=const.$ and $y=const.$ under the complex sine $z \mapsto \sin(z)$ and the square function $z \mapsto z^2$.

I have written the lines in the following form

\begin{align*}
l_1&=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x=a=const.\} \\
l_2&=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=b=const.\} 
\end{align*}

For the images of the lines under $\sin$ I get the equations

\begin{align*}
\sin(a+iy)&=\sin(a) \cosh(y)+i \cos(a) \sinh(y) \\
\sin(x+ib)&=\sin(x) \cosh(b)+i \cos(x) \sinh(b)
\end{align*}

which are the equations of a hyperbola and an ellipse respectiely.

For the images of the lines under $z^2$ I get the equations

\begin{gather}
v+iw=(a+iy)^2=a^2-y^2+2iay  \tag{1} 
\\
v+iw=(x+ib)^2=x^2-b^2+i2bx. \tag{2}
\end{gather}

The square function can also be rewritten in polar coordinates

$$
r_1 e^{i \beta}=r^2_2 e^{2 i \alpha}  
$$

which implies $\beta=2 \alpha$. I also have

$$
\alpha
=\begin{cases}
\text{arctan} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)                , & x>0 \\
\frac{\pi}{2}+\text{arctan} \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)  , & y>0 \\
-\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{arctan} \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) , & y<0.
\end{cases}
$$

However I do not see how to proceed and actually determine the image.

For the preimages of the lines under $\sin$ I get the equations

$$
a+iy
=\sin(v+iw)
=\sin(v) \cosh(w)+i \cos(v) \sinh(w) \\
x+ib
=\sin(v+iw)
=\sin(v) \cosh(w)+ i \cos(v) \sinh(w). 
$$

These impose the conditions $a=\sin(v) cosh(w)$ and $b=cos(v) \sinh(w)$ respectively. However I do not see what these equations are supposed to represent.

For the preimages of the lines under $z^2$ I get the equations

$$
a+iy
=(v+iw)^2
=v^2-w^2+i 2 vw \\
x+ib
=(v+iw)^2
=v^2-w^2+i 2vw
$$

These impose the conditions $a=v^2-w^2$ and $b=2 vw$ which are equations for hyperbolas. The cases $a=0$ and $b=0$ are special cases where the hyperbolas degenerate into pairs of intersecting lines.

So my issue is about determining the images of the lines under $z^2$ and the preimages of the lines under $\sin$.

Comment: You're almost there: The images of the lines under squaring may be more apparent if you write the paths in (real) Cartesian form: $y \mapsto (a^2 - y^2, 2ay)$, etc. <> For the preimages under sine, you have $a = \sin v \cosh w$, which can at least be solved for $v$ as a function of $w$, etc.